# Changes in iTunes Connect?

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

Apple has recently changed the portal. Some of the changes are aery good, but I found two problems:

A. After uploading a binary, I am getting a new status: Upload recieved... and on developer guide they say:

*Appears when your binary has been    received through Application Loader, but has not yet completed processing into the iTunes system. If your app  has been in the Upload Received state    for more than 24 hours, you should    contact iTunes Connect Support    through
the iTunes Connect Contact Us    module.*

B. I cannot replace binary until they chage the status (eiter rejected or ready for sale). This situation is bad sice I found a problem after uploading a binary and I cannot re-upload it.

Comment: That's an old problem. not new... :)

Comment: I agree with Meir. Having to wait hours for the binary to be ready is annoying. I have a binary 12 hours waiting and I need to reject it... a waste of time and annoying as hell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a new status: Upload recieved.
During this status you cannot reload your binary, just be patient until it changes...